# How do I create redirects on a static website?

Tags: html, redirect, jekyll

I have a jekyll website hosted on GitHub pages.

I want to create short links that point elsewhere. For example `example.com/l` can redirect to `linkedin.com/example`.

Is there a way to achieve this on a statically hosted site without messing with my domain registrar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `<meta>` tag added to the `<head>` section of the page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='https://your.redirect.here'" />
```

This will redirect the browser on page load.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`jekyll-redirect-from`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from) plugin for Jekyll, which [allows you to specify that a page should be redirected to a different website](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from#redirect-to).

In your example, you'd create a page called `l.md` with a front-matter that looks like this:

```
---
title: My LinkedIn Profile
redirect_to: https://linkedin.com/example
---
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to create a page for `example.com/l` in jekyll. On that page you can add a `script` tag with

```js
window.location.replace("linkedin.com/example")
```

to [simulate an HTTP redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) or try [ObsoleteAwareProduce's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63033865/7545641) from this tread.